# morphTo and hasMany Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

A quick query regarding some data model relations in Laravel.

I have a product, that belongs to a user, but a user can have many products. But a product can also have many people making an offer on that product so;

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function offer(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
    }
```

But a product can also have different sub types of product, for example, one might be a vehicle, or a mobile phone, each with different columns in my migration, so I assume I need morph many

In `Product.php`

```
public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In `Vehicle.php`

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->morphMany('App\Product', 'imageable');
}
```

However, when calling:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
```

I get null when I attempt do anything like `$product->vehicle`

I add the ID of the vehicle in my database to the `imageable_id` on the products table, and the `imageable` type to 'vehicle' on the products table too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything looks right you just should be accessing it via `imageable`:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
return $product->imageable;
```

From the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations):

> You may also retrieve the owner of a polymorphic relation from the
>   polymorphic model by accessing the name of the method that performs
>   the call to morphTo.

In your case the method that performs the call to `morphTo` is imageable.

Comment: Thats getting me further thank you, however I now get `'Class 'vehicle' not found'`

Comment: How are you storing the data in the polymorphic table? In the database the imageable_type should be like this: `App\Vehicle`

Comment: Ah you're right it was the App\Vehicle in the database, thanks Chase!! (i'll mark correct when SO lets me)

Comment: Glad to hear I was able to help!

Comment: You are fast, @chasenyc